# How to fix map offset of the tales? on Yandex MAP API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I used vue-yandex-maps [this plugin](https://vue-yandex-maps.github.io/en/guide/#installing)! And i have some problem with offset of tales on Map!

You can see this:
[image: picture]

You can see my code, i cannot understand and fix this issues:

```
<template>
  <yandex-map :settings="settings" :coords="coords" zoom="10">
    <ymap-marker :coords="coords" marker-id="123123" marker-type="placemark" />
  </yandex-map>
</template>

<script>
import { yandexMap, loadYmap, ymapMarker } from "vue-yandex-maps";

export default {
  components: { yandexMap, ymapMarker },
  data() {
    return {
      coords: [54.82896654088406, 39.831893822753904],
      settings: {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBgLAe7N_MdFpuVofMkcQLGwwhUu5tuxls",
        lang: "ru_RU",
        // coordorder: "latlong",
        version: "2.1",
        type: "yandex#map",
        behaviors: ["default", "scrollZoom"]
      },
      place: null // optional
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let { settings } = this;
    loadYmap({ settings, debug: true });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm testing on Codepen and it's giving me invalid API key

Comment: sorry i changed API key

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake! In a global scc i have a code for all tags padding and margin:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* ... */
}
```

And i changed this:

```
body,
html,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* ... */
}
```

It works for me!